# Corrupt-looking Accumulation Buffer output

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am in the process of building a simple 3D game engine that is built on top of OpenGL, and for windowing and I/O, GLUT. I have run into a problem with the OpenGL accumulation buffer when trying to build a motion-blur option into the engine. Essentially, here is the small block of code that is supposed to do this for me:

```
glAccum(GL_MULT, 0.99f);
glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 1.0f - 0.99f);
glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1.0f);
```

I first tried this block of code by planting it in my `Render()` method, but it showed a corrupt-looking view where only a select few pixels were visible. So, I then tried it with the rest of the source from the website from which I found the code. I still got the same issue. Below is an image of the issue:

[image: Output of accumulation buffer.]

Then, I just took out the accumulation buffer portion (the three lines that are supposed to achieve the motion blur), and here is what I got:

[image: Correct looking, but no motion blur as expected]

Of course, there would be no motion blur since I removed the `glAccum()` lines, but that at least told me there is either a problem with my graphics card (it doesn't like accumulation buffers?) or those lines of code don't work.

I don't know if it matters, but I am running the code through NetBeans 7.2 (C++) on a MacBook Pro from 2011. Also, I *did* request an accumulation buffer in the following line:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_ACCUM | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
```

Here is a sample piece of code I just threw together. I'm not sure if something is wrong in the code, and I know I probably didn't use best practices either, but it gets the point across. I still experienced the error with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>

using namespace std;

float Rotation = 0.0f;

void Reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1.0f * ((float)height / (float)width), 1.0f * ((float)height / (float)width), 0.1f, 200.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void Update(int value)
{
    Rotation++;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(17, Update, 0);
}

void InitGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glClearDepth(100.0f);
}

void Render(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 5.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glRotatef(Rotation, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        /* Render Icosahedron */
        glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glutSolidIcosahedron();

        /* Render wireframe */
        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glLineWidth(2.0);
        glutWireIcosahedron();
    }
    glPopMatrix();

    /* Blur */
    glAccum(GL_MULT, 0.99);
    glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 0.01);
    glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1.0);

    glFlush();

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ACCUM);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(Render);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);

    InitGL();
    Reshape(400, 400);

    glutTimerFunc(17, Update, 0);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea of how opengl works, but writing `0.01` as `1.0f - 0.99f` makes me wonder if that is intended...

Comment: Does `glGet()` and `GL_ACCUM_[RED|BLUE|GREEN]_BITS` say that you actually got some accumulation buffer bits?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I initially had it `1.0f - MotionBlurIntensity`, but thought it would be easier just to fill in that variable's value when posting the code here.

Comment: @genpfault `glGetIntegerv(GL_ACCUM_[RED|GREEN|BLUE]_BITS, &output)` all gave 32 bits as a result.

Comment: Have you cleared the accumulation buffer?

Comment: Also note that this is deprecated functionality, and probably not so well used before that, so I wouldn't be terribly surprised to find it non-functional in some drivers.

Comment: @JasonD If it is cleared in the `Render()` method, the problem persists with the spottiness and what I call corrupt-looking, only the slight amounts of visible motion blur are also gone since that data is stored in the accum. buffer.

Comment: @JasonD That's a good call. I've read other places that the only solid way to go about doing this is using shaders, but then I saw a three-line code block, and everyone knows how beautiful short code is. I just couldn't resist.

Comment: The weird part though is that the motion blur effect works just fine within those parts of the view that are _actually_ visible.

Comment: Can you maybe hack together a real minimal one file example with compiler call that people can try? Maybe it really is a problem on your system only, or at least people can confirm that how you do it is really not working everywhere, or even play with the code until it works...

Comment: Yeah, looks like the buffer isn't fully set up, but it's trying to render it anyway and you're getting garbage. Works for me locally in a quickly hacked test.

Comment: @JasonD that's interesting, and good to know. Hopefully I can get it to work too.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am hacking together a little test for it right now and I'll add it to the question in just a few minutes for others to try.

Comment: Oh wow! I just got it to work when the window is about 3x as tall as it is wide. I wonder why...?